# How to specify exactly jar version to dependency in java?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I met problem when my project and jar which is used in my project did not used the same version.

Below is my pom.xml in my project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
    <artifactId>sshd-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.another.project.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>exampleserver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

My exampleserver jar is using sshd-core version 0.14.0, but my project is using sshd-core version 1.6.0. So it will be failed because all implementation of sshd-core 0.14.0 and sshd-core version 1.6.0 is different.

Are there anyway to specify exactly sshd version for exampleserver ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The only solution which exists is to migrate the example-server to the newer version...

Answer (score 1):

The unfortunate reality is that you can have just one version of a given jar when you compile/run the project. So you need to decide which version of `sshd-core version` is ok for all uses in your project (including transitive ones).

If you figure out that version `x.y.z` is a good fit both for your project and `exampleserver` you can set it through `<dependencyManagement>`. If this version happens to be `1.6.0` you can also use the exclusion mechanism described in the other answers.

If you do not find a version that fits for all purposes, you will have a hard time. You can try class shading or you need to rewrite the code.

Comment: It is a hard time with me because I'm not allowed to upgrade sshd-core version in exampleserver. Thank you.

Comment: Just to make sure you understood me correctly: You do not need to change the version in the pom of sshd-core. DependencyManagement is only in your own pom. But you need to find a version, like e.g. 1.0.0 that works with both your project and the exampleserver.

Answer (score 0):

The sshd version from exampleserver is defined in the POM of exampleserver. If this is not your project, you cannot change that version. What you could do, however, is exclude the sshd dependency from exampleserver, so that you will only have the 1.6.0 version on your classpath. E.g.:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.another.project.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>exampleserver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
            <artifactId>sshd-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use exclusions.

> Since maven 2.x resolves dependencies transitively, it is possible for unwanted dependencies to be included in your project's classpath.

(https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html):

In your example

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.another.project.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>exampleserver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
            <artifactId>sshd-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```